# Running a for loop after jquery post success

Tags: php, jquery

I am posting a list of numeric ids to my php script for deletion

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
var arr = $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').map(function(i, e) {
        return +e.id;
    }).get();
    var checkedArr = arr.join(',');
$.post('delete.php', {thearray: checkedArr }, function(data) {
for(var row_id in data) {
  $("#"+data[row_id]).remove();
}
});
});
```

and then returning the ids i had just posted

```
$.post('delete.php', {thearray: checkedArr }, function(data) {
for(var row_id in data) {
  $("#"+data[row_id]).remove();
}
});
```

How can i run the for loop so that i can delete the rows?.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "caliban");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$incoming = $_POST['thearray'];
$query="DELETE FROM caliban where id in ($incoming)";
$mysqli->query($query);
echo $incoming;
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I however cannot delete the rows on success.

Comment: I can't figure out from the question what you are trying to do on client side, and what on server side

Comment: why not send another request on `success` to do the delete on the server-side?

Comment: I am trying to delete multiple rows on the client side.I am able to delete the rows on the server side.

Comment: Did you echo $query to check what is actual query string is ?

Comment: So, the server side code (where the rows are removed from the database) is working fine (albeit unsafely - you may want to sanitise `$incoming`), but you're unable to remove the DOM elements of the table rows on the client side for the rows which have been deleted?

Comment: Yes,that is the case.I have got numeric ids in the form of 34,23,22,44 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rows are already in the array `arr`, which is in your scope in the success function, you could simply try

```
for (var row_id in arr) {
    // remove
}
```

Or, if you want to ensure you're removing the IDs which the server is sending back, you could try

```
for (var row_id in data.split(',')) {
    // remove
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because that in your success callback, `data` is a string, not an array. You should use your `arr` variable that contains the same IDs but in a actual array.

Moreover, you should not run your query like this:
1) Send an array to your PHP script, not a string.
2) Use PDO library.
3) Use prepared queries. It is not secure at all to put `$incoming` directly in the query string.

Comment: There's no obligation to switch from mysqli to PDO, that's a choice, and same with prepared statements. If they were mysql_* functions, it would be a different matter. Additionally, there's no reason in this code to say that the data should be sent as an array - it's going to have to be serialised at some point, somehow, and since he knows it's just a list of numbers, using comma separated is fine.

Comment: It is choice, I concede, but it's a good habit to escape user input in queries and prepared statements are a good solution. For the array, it was precisely in order to directly bind parameters. But, I agree, there is no reason, otherwise.